# adding a second function to the array that is working with indexes of array

Tags: c

I have a code that works perfectly, its finding average of all numbers that were put in the array and its finding average of a section of array. I just need to make second function that is working with the array with its indexes.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double priemer(double *pole, int dlzka);

    int main()
    {
        int i, dlzka;
        printf("Zadaj velkost pola: ");
        scanf("%d", &dlzka);
        while (dlzka < 1)
        {
            printf("Chyba! Cislo musi byt viac, ako 0.\n");
            printf("Zadaj pocet prvkov znova: ");
            scanf("%d", &dlzka);
        }
        double *pole = malloc(dlzka * sizeof(double));
        for(i = 0; i < dlzka; i++)
        {
            printf("cislo %d: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%lf", &pole[i]);
        }
        printf("Priemer vsetkych prvkov v poli je: %.3lf\n", priemer(pole, dlzka));
        int zaciatok, koniec;
        printf("Zadaj zaciatok useku: \n");
        scanf("%d", &zaciatok);
        printf("Zadaj koniec useku: \n");
        scanf("%d", &koniec);
        if(koniec > dlzka || zaciatok > koniec || zaciatok < 1)
        {
            printf("Zly vstup");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Priemer od %d. do %d. prvku je: %.3lf\n", zaciatok, koniec, priemer(pole + (zaciatok - 1), koniec - (zaciatok - 1)));
        return 0;
    }
    
    double priemer(double *pole, int dlzka)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < dlzka; i++)
        {
            sum += pole[i];
        }
        return sum/dlzka;
    }
```

Comment: at first glance, the posted code does the desired functionality.  Therefore, what is your question?